wiring in ceiling does not match switch in wall
I am replacing a light fixture with a ceiling fan that has a light.  the wires coming out of the ceiling are 1 red, 2 black, 2 white and the ground wires.  on the light switch I have red and black.  what wires should be put together in order to make the switch give my fan power?
there is a second switch next to this one that controls a set of can lights in the ceiling and appears that we have both the fan and the can lights on and off together.  How would we wire this properly?
the only thing we did is hook black to black, white to white and ground to ground.  i capped off the red wire since I was not sure what to hook it to.

Sounds like you need another switched wire from a double switch to run your fan separately to the light.

There are lots of questions to be answered here. What are your desires here?  Do you want the light to work with a switch independently from the fan?  Is the box in the ceiling rated for a fan?  Have you checked the red and black wires to see which are switched hot and which are constant hot?  Does the fan have a remote that you will be using?

You can't randomly connect wires together! You have to know for sure which has power and which are switched. Otherwise you may short something out and damage your fan or worse.


what wires should be put together in order to make the switch give my fan power?

"on the light switch I have red and black"- seems like the black at the switch brings live power (hot/line) to the switch; the red wire brings switched power to the ceiling box.

what wires should be put together in order to make the switch give my fan power?

"the wires coming out of the ceiling are 1 red, 2 black, 2 white and the ground wires" - Connect the red to the black wire on your fan/light unit; this is the switched hot coming from the switch (sometimes you also need to connect to a blue wire on your fan/light unit, for the lights). Connect the blacks together (they probably carry power through to something else). Connect the whites together (they probably carry neutral through to something else) along with a short additional white wire (pigtail) which will be connected to the white wire from your fan/light unit.
Note- above assumes there are 2 cables in the ceiling box, one with 3 wires (white, black, red) and one with 2 wires (white, black). Grounds not mentioned/included because they should be self-evident...

there is a second switch next to this one that controls a set of can lights in the ceiling and appears that we have both the fan and the can lights on and off together. How would we wire this properly?

It is not clear what you are saying here. More information is needed (pictures?) to understand the situation, and your intent is not clear (do you want the fan and can lights to work together or separate?)
